# Why does a generic class implementing a generic interface with type constraints need to repeat these constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

Let's say I have a following C# interface:

```
public interface IInterface<T> where T : SomeClass
{
    void InterfaceMethod();
}
```

And SomeClass is defined as follows:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod();
}
```

Now I'd like to define the implementation of the interface, which won't compile:

```
public class InterfaceImpl<T> : IInterface<T> 
{
    public void InterfaceMethod()
    {
        T test = default(T);
        test.SomeMethod(); //Gives Error
    }
}
```

before I change it to:

```
public class InterfaceImpl<T> : IInterface<T> where T : SomeClass
{
    public void InterfaceMethod()
    {
        T test = default(T);
        test.SomeMethod(); //Compiles fine
    }
}
```

Wouldn't it make sense that the type constraints are also "inherited" (not the right word, I know) from the interface?

Comment: They could probably have been realized "by default", if nothing was specified. But the actual syntax allows to redefine the constraints (inheritance, new() keyword, etc) which is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class does not need to repeat these constraints, it needs to supply a type that *satisfies* the constraints of the interface. There are several ways of doing it:

- It can supply a specific type that satisfies the constraints, or
- It can place its own constraints on a generic type that are *stronger* than what the interface expects, or
- It can repeat the constraints from the interface.

The key thing is that `T` in `InterfaceImpl<T>` belongs to `InterfaceImpl`, so whatever constraints that are placed on `T` must be `InterfaceImpl`'s own.

Comment: Very nice and clear explanation, the last sentence was crucial for me:) Knowing your answer, the only thing I don't understand is why will C# allow me to create a class that doesn't do any of the things mentioned in your answer? Say, it's some abstract class that doesn't call methods of T - I can compile it without putting any constraints on T or specifying the type, which would satisfy the constraints of interface.

Comment: @BartekEborn I am not sure what you mean. In situations when a generic interface has a constraint, a class implementing it needs to supply a compatible parameter, regardless of whether the implementing class is abstract or not ([demo - does not compile](http://ideone.com/WG9pR1)). I'm sure you meant something else. Could you make a demo that shows what you mean? You can click "fork" on my demo, and modify it if you prefer.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. My bad, I'm sorry for your effort. I trusted Intellisense which didn't highlight the error in such case (although it did in the earlier). After actually testing it, I feel ashamed:( Sorry once more!